# Why are parameters being incorrectly interpreted in this PowerShell ampersand command?

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I have a PowerShell script which is as follows:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    # Other parameters removed for brevity
    [string] $MSBuildParameters = ""
)
# Other syntax removed for brevity
& $MSBuild $Solution /p:Configuration=$Configuration /p:Platform="$BuildPlatform" /nologo /m /v:m /nr:false $MSBuildParameters
```

- `$MSBuild` is an instance of `ApplicationInfo` from `Get-Command "MSBuild.exe"`
- `$Solution` is a path to a `.sln` or `.csproj` file.
- `$MSBuildParameters` contains zero or more parameters to be passed on the command line verbatim.

The $MSBuildParameters variable is passed in from another PowerShell script as follows:

```
& .\Build.ps1 -MSBuildParameters "/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=MyProfile"
```

However, when the command executes, MSBuild blaps with the following error:

> error MSB4100: Expected "$(_DeployOnBuild)" to evaluate to a boolean instead of "true /p:Publ
>   ishProfile=FolderProfile", in condition "'$(PipelineDeployPhaseAfterTargets)' == '' And $(_DeployOnBuild)

What's going on here?

Comment: Maybe it is worth noting that these command line arguments work correctly if they're written explicitly rather than being passed in through `$MSBuildParameters`.

Comment: Have you tried passing it as an array of strings (`& .\Build.ps1 -MSBuildParameters "/p:DeployOnBuild=true","/p:PublishProfile=MyProfile"`), and changing the parameter to `[string[]]$MSBuildParameters`?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Same behavior as described in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always the `Invoke-Expression` approach where you build the command string, and then invoke the string as an expression. Something like:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    # Other parameters removed for brevity
    [string] $MSBuildParameters = ""
)
# Other syntax removed for brevity
$cmd = "& `$MSBuild '$Solution' /p:Configuration=$Configuration /p:Platform=`"$BuildPlatform`" /nologo /m /v:m /nr:false $MSBuildParameters"
Invoke-Expression $cmd
```

That way your strings are expanded beforehand, and it should behave just like it would if you were to type it all out manually. Note that I did escape the `$MSBuild` object, as well as the inner quotes, so that they would be retained as is, and I added single quotes around the solution path in case it has spaces. You may need to make adjustments to the quotes I retained and added.

Comment: The exact expression I used was `$MSBuildCommand = "& $MSBuild '$Solution' /p:Configuration=$Configuration /p:Platform='$BuildPlatform' /nologo /m /v:m /nr:false $MSBuildParameters"`, and this worked. Marking as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your goal, I'd recommend trying an array of strings and joining them.

e.g.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
  # Other parameters removed for brevity
  [string] $MSBuildParameters = ""
)
# Other syntax removed for brevity
$params = @("$solution", "/p:Configuration=$Configuration", "/p:Platform=$BuildPlatform", "nologo", "/m", "/v:m", "/nr:false", "$MSBuildParameters")
$params = $params -join " "
& "$MSBuild" $params
```

Comment: This is causing even more troubles. I've done [this](https://pastebin.com/m965FZKd) but now MSBuild.exe gags on a space in the $Solution parameter.

Comment: @Kivin parameters with spaces should be quoted to be interpreted as a single argument.